# How to query Jenkins using java

Tags: java, jenkins

I am programming using java to fetch few information from Jenkins url. I am trying to get information on nodes, projects created etc. All these are get commands. On browsing about it, I reached following link:

http://javadoc.jenkins.io/

I tried using import statement "import hudson.cli.GetNodeCommand;". But it is throwing me error : The import hudson.cli.GetNodeCommand cannot be resolved.

I have imported jars from my JEnkins url ( https://jenkins.example.com/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar). How do I resolve this? I downloaded this jar from github also and that also has same structure as in the screen shot below. There is no GetNodeCommand class inside 'hudson.cli' package. How do I fetch information about nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `hudson.cli.GetNodeCommand` is part of Jenkins core, and not part of the CLI client JAR.  See the [developer documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/building/) for pointers to building Jenkins itself, if you want to do something with these classes.

If you want to execute `GetNodeCommand`, you can do so by running the [CLI client](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) with the `get-node` command, e.g.: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar get-node node-name`.

A list of all CLI commands available in a given Jenkins installation can be found at `https://<jenkins-host>/cli/`.

If you want to fetch information not available via the provided CLI commands, the standard way to do so is the [Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console), which enables you to write Groovy to access the Jenkins APIs.  This functionality is also exposed through the CLI via the `groovy` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher. I am new to Java. I use Jenkins on daily basis to build jobs (as Jenkins admin). But now I need to do some automation using Java. Automation like fetching few reports for nodes, jobs and creating new nodes etc. So I was trying to first fetch information and I thought GetNodeCommand would help(for getting node info). Is there any way that I can program in Java and do it? I have no idea about Groovy as of now.

Comment: Jenkins has an [API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), and there's a [Java API client](https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api).